# Distributional Laplacian is in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Assume that $-\Delta u = f$ in the $H^1_0 (\Omega)$ weak sense.

Is it true that $f \in L^2 \implies f = -\Delta u \in L^2$?

Let me be more precise. I define the functional $\langle- \Delta u , v \rangle:=\int \nabla u \nabla v$ for $v \in H^1_0$. Now I know that $\langle- \Delta u , v \rangle = \int fv$, hence, by density, the "distributional Laplacian" has a representative $-\Delta u \in L^2$, that  is to say, by the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations, $f =- \Delta u \in L^2$.

Is this correct, under the assumption that the domain is e.g. bounded Lipschitz?

Comment: This is correct. Dificulties arise if you want to get from $\Delta u \in L^2$ to $u\in H^2$.